# SQL Server rename table with name start #

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 with a view called `##_AD_DA_RISTAMPARE`

When I try to rename or delete it in SQL Server Management Studio, I receive an error that the table or the view does not exists.

Unfortunately I have those views, I think they where renamed with ##_ in sql server 2005 or sqlserver 2000 anche after the system update we cannot delete it

Comment: You can't have a *view* of that name. `CREATE VIEW [##_AD_DA_RISTAMPARE] AS SELECT 1 AS X` gives `Temporary views are not allowed.`

Answer (score 5):

When you create a table starting with `##`, it is treated as **Global temporary tables** are visible to everyone, and are deleted when all connections that have referenced them have closed.

Thus it is a possibility you view is deleted from database, thus you are getting error.

You can not have a view whose name starts with `##` as

```
CREATE VIEW [##_AD_DA_RISTAMPARE] AS SELECT 1
```

Gives Error

```
"##_AD_DA_RISTAMPARE": Temporary views are not allowed.
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have those views, I think they where renamed with ##_ in sql server 2005 or sqlserver 2000 anche after the system update we cannot delete it